# Cleaning the data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

I'm doing the sentiment analysis on crpytocurrency. My job is to clean the data from the csv file. The data was generated(From Twitter) and saved in a csv file. Before doing the sentiment Analysis part. I have to clean the data .For example, Delete the punctuations, the URLs, put the test in a lower case. Those are the tweets.

## I already imported useful libraries for example NLTK(Natural language processing), pandas, numpy, and others.

Here's the output for the 'Tweets' Column.

```
   ctweet['Tweets'][0:6]



 Out[5]:


    0    RT @TheLTCnews: The @LTCFoundation has publish...
    1    RT @WildchildSings: "https:/ " + /t.co/"FZrGw6xsZU ac..."
    2    RT @HODL_Whale: 5 days until #LitePay launches...
    3    LTC to USD price $211.92 "https:/" + /t.co/"CFjg1mIg..."
    4    LTC to BTC price B0.020218 "https:/" +/t.co/"XPL8NI..."
    5    LTC to GBP price £151.89 "https:/" +/t.co/"iOIbhgyd..."
    6    Litecoin dropped into the bear zone as sugges...
    Name: Tweets, dtype: object

# the output contains url. Because stackoverflow won't allow me to post the url. I have to change the method for url like adding "quotes" and "//".
```

My next task was to clean the data. Here's the preprocessing code.

```
#Preprocessing del RT @blablabla:
ctweet['tweetos'] = '' 

#add tweetos first part
for i in range(len(ctweet['Tweets'])):
    try:
        ctweet['tweetos'][i] = ctweet['Tweets'].str.split(' ')[i][0]
    except AttributeError:    
        ctweet['tweetos'][i] = 'other'

        #Preprocessing tweetos. select tweetos contains 'RT @'
        for i in range(len(ctweet['Tweets'])):
            if ctweet['tweetos'].str.contains('@')[i]  == False:
                ctweet['tweetos'][i] = 'other'

        # remove URLs, RTs, and twitter handles
        for i in range(len(ctweet['Tweets'])):
            ctweet['Tweets'][i] = " ".join([word for word in ctweet['Tweets'][i].split()
                                        if 'http' not in word and '@' not in word and '<' not in word])

  ctweet['Tweets'][0]
```

The code above it will delete the punctuation, the urls, put test in a lower case, extract username for examples. When I run that code it gives an error.

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8254e078073a> in <module>()
      5 for i in range(len(ctweet['Tweets'])):
      6     try:
----> 7         ctweet['tweetos'][i] = ctweet['Tweets'].str.split(' ')[i][0]
      8     except AttributeError:
      9         ctweet['tweetos'][i] = 'other'

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What does that error mean? How can I solve this problem. Im using Jupyter Notebook 5.4.1

### Update part

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bb6b24f62739> in <module>()
     16 # remove URLs, RTs, and twitter handles
     17 for i in range(len(ctweet['Tweets'])):
---> 18     ctweet['Tweets'][i] = " ".join([word for word in ctweet['Tweets'][i].split()
     19                                 if 'http' not in word and '@' not in word and '<' not in word])
     20 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: i think this `ctweet['Tweets'].str.split(' ')[i][0]` should be like `ctweet['Tweets'][i].str.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: -Hamza Haider , I did that. Thought the code is gonna run correctly but got another error on line 18  

' ctweet['Tweets'][i] = " ".join([word for word in ctweet['Tweets'][i].split() ' 


"AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: ok well it seems like `ctweet['Tweets'][i]` isnt always string, in this case it's a float. Can you confirm this all items in `ctweet['Tweets']` are strings?

Comment: every value in the 'Tweets' column are not strings.

Comment: well there's your problem then since you're doing `.split()` on every value of 'Tweets' columns then it will fail if you hit a non string value.

Comment: So, do i need to convert all the values from 'Tweets' column  into String?

Comment: Hamza Haider. I got the code working. I had to convert the values into Strings. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ctweet is a dictionary, so you need to point an index like following:

`ctweet['tweetos'][i] = ctweet['Tweets'][i].str.split(' ')[0]`

instead of:

`ctweet['tweetos'][i] = ctweet['Tweets'].str.split(' ')[i][0]`